# Using ReactRouter withRouter doesn't work with a React Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

It seems that I can not use a React Hook `useState` inside of a Functional component that is wrapped in a `withRouter` function call for React Router.

I need the `withRouter` call to get URL parameters from the browser.

```js
function TheComponent(props) {
    const { id } = props.match.params;
    // this is returning null for both done & setDone
    const {done, setDone} = useState(false);

    // some code that's using id

    return <div>
       // some tags here
    </div>
}

export default withRouter(function(props) {
     return <TheComponent {...props} {...this}  />
});
```

Adding the `withRouter` stops the Hook from working it seems.

How do I get around this?

I tried to add the Hook in the function call, but that didn't work:

```js
export default withRouter(function(props) {
     const {done, setDone} = useState(false);
     return <TheComponent {...props} {...this} done={done} setDone={setDone}  />
});
```

The main thing I need to understand I suppose is what is the limitations of Hooks? It seems that they can't be declared inside the `withRouter` HOC function. Is that correct? And how can I get around this as I need to user the URL parameters for which I need the `withRouter` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax for what the useState function returns. You should use square brackets instead of curly braces.

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-what-do-square-brackets-mean) for useState:

```
const [fruit, setFruit] = useState('banana');
```

> When we declare a state variable with useState, it returns a pair — an
>   array with two items. The first item is the current value, and the
>   second is a function that lets us update it. Using [0] and [1](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-what-do-square-brackets-mean) to
>   access them is a bit confusing because they have a specific meaning.
>   This is why we use array destructuring instead.

Edit: As others have said you should also be passing a props value as a parameter into your function.

Comment: Eish! Indeed that was the issue. Nothing todo with React Router in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add arguments to your components:

```
function TheComponent(props) {
    const { id } = props.match.params;
    // this is returning null for both done & setDone
    const {done, setDone} = useState(false);

    // some code that's using id

    return <div>
       // some tags here
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that your not getting the props in the constructor of TheComponent, but in case it breaks the rules of hooks, you can use this other aproach.

```
const TheComponent = (match) => {
        //you can destruct from props direct on parameters if you want
        const { id } = match.params;
        const [done, setDone] = useState(false);

        return <div>
           // some tags here
        </div>
    }

    export const WrapperComponent = withRouter((props) => {
      //you can destruct from props direct on parameters if you want
      const { match } = props;
      return <TheComponent match={match} />
    });
```

Comment: Not sending in the `props` was typo in my question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: NP, I actually checked that the problem was tuple vs object destructing, this is really trick to get sometime, nice you got it fixed.